# How to get a variable passenger arrival rate out of a schedule?

Tags: distribution, schedule, anylogic

I'm about to setup an airport Check-In Terminal with anylogic.
I already loaded a "test" excel file which contains the relevant data : *Flight*, *C/I start time*, *C/I end time* and *number of C/I passengers (n)*.

Next I created a *schedule*: Type: *int* (start column: *C/I start time*, End column: *C/I end time*, value column: *n*;
I've linked  my *pedSource* accordingly: Arrive according to: *Arrival schedule*, Arrival schedule: *schedule*:

It works so far, but all the passengers arrive as a group at the beginning of the C/I time. How can i implement a distribution, so that the number of passengers (n) arrive divided up during the C/I period?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to calculate your interarrival times. Here is what I do in this case:
In Source block, I select interarrival time as option and assume that these interarrivals will be exponentially distributed.

So, if you want to distribute 10 check-in arrivals during an hour, you can use `exponential(10)` as the interarrival distribution. Please see the screenshot below. I update `trucks1` dynamically during the simulation to have different number of arrivals for different hours.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your input. My problem is, that i do not have passenger data of every full hour.
There are quite a lot overlapping timeslot for the check-in process. So for example for the first flight, i need a distribution of 85 passengers starting from 04:35 till 05:35 o'clock, while parallel from 04:45 to 05:45 the next check in passengers are already coming...

Comment: I would do the following:

- Aggregate all arrivals hourly, use exponential interarrival time (explained in the answer) and then assign a probability for the agent to approach to which check-in.